# Template for Excel Exports

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create an excel sheet that pulls data from an export with the click of a button. I was wondering if there was a way to code something that pulls from a different export everyday and still uses the same code?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to import data into excel from another workbook and have this perform daily? Is that what you are asking? If so then heres a tutorial on importing data http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/import-sheets.html

Comment: Well whats happening right now is that a user is pulling an excel export report from one of our applications everyday and then performs all these tedious formatting steps. What I want is to have another excel sheet up that has a button that performs all these formatting issues but pulls the data from the different daily excel exports.... so its different workbooks everyday.

Comment: Well if they are named consistently (eg sheet-date.xls) then you could just import the sheet from a folder where filename = "sheet-" + todaysdate + ".xls" with todaysdate being found using vbas inbuilt now function.

Comment: They all have a weird number naming format I cannot control :/ but they all have the same worksheet name... I dont know if you can do anything with just that though lol

Comment: if theyre all just in the same folder you could just import the latest one. Like here: https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/880254-get-most-recent-file-folder-then-import-transfertext-into-table

Comment: Ahh ok well if I can just get them to save them to a folder then I could just do that. Sweet thank you!

Comment: I think that may be from an older version of Excel do you know what you would use instead of file and folder when dim'ing your variables?

Comment: Pretty sure you need to go into tools->references and add the 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' to you list by ticking it.

Answer (score 0):

To make your sub automated I would use auto_open in excel sheet and have a windows task scheduler set up to run once a day. Follow some tutorials to write the actual sub that imports the data, ask here if you get stuck.

Comment: Ok I think I have decided to use what you said earlier and just get everyone to have the same naming convention by date but I have no idea where to even start the code

Comment: OK so to check what you need. You have a folder of files called 'data_12-02-16.xls' or something and other dates all in the same format? And you want a vba macro to import that data each day from the days sheet? eg on the 12th you import data from sheet dated 12th etc?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want to happen but I have no idea how to do that  :/